# PHP - MYSQL - SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have little problem with inserting data to my database.
I get this error but i have no idea way. I have almost identical query on other script and it works fine but this one does not. I check the POST data on chrome inspector it shows fine.

if you have idea whats wrong with it, let me know.
Thanks in Advance.

```
$fact_total = (float)$_POST['precio'];
 $fact_btax = (float)$_POST['precio_sin'];
 $fact_tax = (float)$_POST['impuestos'];
 $fact_name = e($_POST['fact_name']);
 $fact_tipo = e($_POST['fact_serv']);

  $fact_tax_rate = 21;

    try{
      $handler = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO fact_info
        (id_client, cl_name, cl_last_name, cl_last_name_2, cl_email, cl_tel, cl_doc_type, cl_doc, cl_via, cl_street, cl_number, cl_level, cl_stairs, cl_door, cl_provincia, cl_city, cl_cod_postal, fact_urgencia, fact_name, fact_tipo, fact_total, fact_btax, fact_tax, fact_tax_rate, created ) VALUES (:id_client, :cl_name, :cl_last_name, :cl_last_name_2, :cl_email, :cl_tel, :cl_doc_type, :cl_doc, :cl_via, :cl_street, :cl_number, :cl_level, :cl_stairs, :cl_door, :cl_provincia, :cl_city, :cl_cod_postal, :fact_urgencia, :fact_name, :fact_tipo, :fact_total, :fact_btax, :fact_tax, :pres_tax_rate, NOW())');
      $handler->execute(array(
        ':id_client' => $client_ids,
        ':cl_name' => e($_POST['fact_cl_name']),
        ':cl_last_name' => e($_POST['fact_lastname']),
        ':cl_last_name_2' => e($_POST['fact_lastname_2']),
        ':cl_email' => e($_POST['fact_email']),
        ':cl_tel' => e($_POST['fact_tel']),
        ':cl_doc_type' => e($_POST['fact_document_type']),
        ':cl_doc' => e($_POST['fact_document_number']),
        ':cl_via' => e($_POST['fact_dir_via']),
        ':cl_street' => e($_POST['fact_dir_calle']),
        ':cl_number' => (int)$_POST['fact_dir_number'],
        ':cl_level' => e($_POST['fact_dir_level']),
        ':cl_stairs' => e($_POST['fact_dir_stairs']),
        ':cl_door' => e($_POST['fact_dir_door']),
        ':cl_provincia' => e($_POST['fact_dir_provincia']),
        ':cl_city' => e($_POST['fact_dir_localidad']),
        ':cl_cod_postal' => (int)$_POST['fact_dir_cod_postal'],
        ':fact_urgencia' => '1',
        ':fact_name' => $fact_name,
        ':fact_tipo' => $fact_tipo,
        ':fact_total' => $fact_total,
        ':fact_btax' => $fact_btax,
        ':fact_tax' => $fact_tax,
        ':fact_tax_rate' => $fact_tax_rate
      ));

    $fact_id = $db->lastInsertId();

    foreach ($_POST['inv_desc'] as $key => $value) {
        $handler4 = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO fact_content (id_fact, fact_desc, fact_qty, fact_price, fact_subtotal) VALUES (:id_fact, :fact_desc, :fact_qty, :fact_price, :fact_subtotal)');
        $handler4->execute(array(
          ':id_fact' => $fact_id,
          ':fact_desc' => e($_POST['inv_desc'][$key]),
          ':fact_qty' => (float)$_POST['inv_qty'][$key],
          ':fact_price' => (float)$_POST['inv_precio'][$key],
          ':fact_subtotal' => (float)$_POST['inv_subtotal'][$key]
          ));
    }

      header('Location: fact_confirm.php?fact_id='.$fact_id.'');
      exit();
```

Comment: It was in the title, but its resolved now.

Comment: Yeap, i saw it a bit late..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll explain you why this error occurs.

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

This error basically occurs because of the following reasons.

**Reason1**

As the error name suggests, there is some `difference` between the number of parameters in your prepared query. What I mean is, take a look at the following example:

```
$s = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO table(column1,column2) values(:column1)
$s->bindParam(':column1', $column1Value);
$s->bindParam(':column2', $column2Value);
```

Now, this will generate the error you mentioned because you're trying to insert into 2 columns, but are only providing value for 1.

**Reason2**

```
$s = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO table(column1) values(:column1,:column2)
$s->bindParam(':column1', $column1Value);
$s->bindParam(':column2', $column2Value);
```

Now this would generate an error because you're trying to insert value into one column, but providing **2** values inside the `VALUE` section of the query.

**Reason3**

```
$s = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO table(column1,column2) values(:column1,:column2)
$s->bindParam(':column1', $column1Value);
```

In this case, you've written the query part correct. However, you missed **binding the parameters for the second value, the `:column2`.**

These are the reasons why this error bumps up. Check your code and you'd find out what error out of these 3 you've made.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explication. It was a typo, in my code.

Comment: This is a nice, well thought out answer. It fails to, however, answer the actual reason why the OP is having issues. This is more of a general answer.

Comment: @FrankerZ
I just thought this would help more people in future. I also gave OP a way to fix his problem ;)

Answer (score 2):

It appears that there is no `:fact_tax_rate`. Looks like a typo. Your last insert statement column inserts `:pres_tax_rate`.

Comment: Thanks. Damn how do i missed that.

Answer (score 1):

Your first insert has the wrong variable name for the second to last value. Change `:pres_tax_rate` to `:fact_tax_rate`

Comment: Thanks, a lot i have missed that detail.